# Where in the bin folder can I see the nhibernate mapping information?

Tags: nhibernate, embedded-resource

If I use *.hbm file as an embedded resource for mapping in nhibernate, where does this information go into? I do not see any mapping files in the bin directory. Does this information get embedded directly into the dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed. Embedded resources are not copied to the output directory, but literally embedded into the .dll file.

You can check with any available decompile tool as well.

Comment: I am looking at the dll with ildasm, but I don't see it. What node does it come under?

Comment: Don't know about ldasm. But if you would use JustDecompile (free), then you can see it under the Resources folder.